# authentification using angularjs, nodejs & passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, passport.js

I can't resolve this problem, I search a lot on th web but nothing help.
I have frontEnd(angular) running on localhost:63447 and backend on localhost:3000(nodejs).
I have a problem only when it's a new user and node have to create it before sending back the reponse. User is beeing created but I get an empty reponse on angular.
I'm sending a post via angular:

```
 $scope.signIn = function(userToSignIn){
        console.log(userToSignIn);
        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/authenticate/signup',
            userToSignIn)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){

                $scope.test = data;;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
                });
```

to a function in nodejs:

```
router.post('/signup',
         function(req, res, next) {
             console.log(req.body);
            passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }//This one is working
                else if (!user) {  return res.json({status: req.session.flash.signupMessage}); }//work
                else if(user) {
                    return res.status(200).json(user._id);//this is the problem

                }
            })(req, res, next);}),
```

Here is the local-signup function:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

},
function(req, email, password, done) {
    // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
    process.nextTick(function() {
        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error

            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {
                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUser            = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.local.email    = email;
                newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('error'); throw err;
                    }else
                        console.log('saved');
                    return done(null, newUser, req.flash('You were successly logged in'));
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: Is the problem that the session not being set as you are not calling [`req.login`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277094/req-session-passport-and-req-user-empty-serializeuser-and-deserializeuser-are-n/28329137#28329137)? If not, please describe the problem.

Comment: I think it is a crossdomain issue. the response from the server is empty only when I call it from another host. Using postman it's working

Comment: Don't now why, but sometimes nodejs give me a 200 and most of time I don't get anything:
**POST /authenticate/signup - - ms - -**

Comment: have you tried setting express to allow cors requests?

Comment: Yes I'vee set the headers. Also it doesn't work only when it have to create the new user

Comment: Maybe the problem is due to my app architecture. I don't understand a lot, but when I send a request to my server in post, It first send it as _OPTION_   type (status 200), then I have a request to my localhost with **x-www-form-urlencoded** and a parameter **token**  - the status of this request is pending then fail I think it's because it sending it to localhost:63442 when my angular is on  localhost:63442/CLIENT/app (localhost:63442 is a 404). Anyway, after all these it makes another request to my SERVER as a post and the email, password.