# passport-local with ajax does not use session

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

When doing an async login to passport-local my session never stores a user and the serialization is never called.

Since I'm not redirecting when I'm done logging in (I just notify the user about it through the response to their ajax call) I guess I'll have to trigger the serialization manually when I've logged in? I'm not sure how the session will have the user associated when they refresh though. This is my main concern since my users never leave the main page in my use case, I do however want them to stay logged in for some period of time after they refresh (unless they explicitly log out).

Any ideas how I can cause passport to save the session when I'm logging in with ajax?

**Configuration**

```
app.use(require('express-session')({secret:'secret'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        user: req.user // undefined here, although req.session does exist. req.session.passport does not exist.
    });
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', {}, function(error, user, info) {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).json(error);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json(info);
        }
        res.json({user: user});
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

**Login call, client side**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/login",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: '{"email":"a@b.c", "password":"abc"}',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        data.user; // valid, this comes back.
    }
});
```

**Serialization (never called)**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serialize user:', user); // never called
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('deserializeUser user:', user); // never called
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log('deserializeUser user (done):', user);
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

**Strategy**

```
var onLocalLoginStrategy = function(req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
        'local.email': email.toUpperCase()
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, { message:'No user found.'} );

        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });

        return done(null, user);
    });
};
```

Comment: have you called `passport.use(YOUR_STRATEGY)` ?

Comment: Hey @NazarSakharenko

Yes, I have. I can successfully log in and register using my strategy. The problem is that I can't get the session to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [req.session.passport and req.user empty, serializeUser and deserializeUser are never called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277094/req-session-passport-and-req-user-empty-serializeuser-and-deserializeuser-are-n)